# How would I convert this to Lat, Long and Alt using String Split?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am currently parsing an XML file to get a coordinate value using the below code.

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            WebClient busStops = new WebClient();
            busStops.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(busStops_DownloadStringCompleted);
            busStops.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.location.com/file.xml"));


        }


        void busStops_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
                return;



            var busStopInfo = XDocument.Load("Content/BusStops2.xml");

            var Transitresults = from root in busStopInfo.Descendants("Placemark")
                                 let StoplocationE1 = root.Element("Point").Element("coordinates")
                                 let nameE1 = root.Element("name")


                                 select new TansitVariables

                                 {

                                     Stoplocation = StoplocationE1 == null ? null : StoplocationE1.Value,
                                     name = nameE1 == null ? null : nameE1.Value,

                                 };


            listBox2.ItemsSource = Transitresults;

        }

        public class TansitVariables
        {
            public string Stoplocation { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }

        }


    }

}
```

the value is in the String StopLocation, but I would like to convert this to 3 values Lat, Long and Alt.

I haven't used String Split before and the documentation doesn't explain how I can do this from a parsed output.

Out is this `174.732224,-36.931053,0.000000`

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this output string, you can get your three numbers via:

```
string result = "174.732224,-36.931053,0.000000";

var items = result.Split(',');
double longitude = double.Parse(items[0]);
double latitude  = double.Parse(items[1]);
double altitude = double.Parse(items[2]);
```

---

Edit:

The portion of your code that would require changing is likely:

```
    var Transitresults = from root in busStopInfo.Descendants("Placemark")
                 let StoplocationE1 = root.Element("Point").Element("coordinates")
                 let nameE1 = root.Element("name")
                 select new TansitVariables(
                      StoplocationE1 == null ? null : StoplocationE1.Value,
                      nameE1 == null ? null : nameE1.Value);

    listBox2.ItemsSource = Transitresults;
}

// Add properties to your class
public class TransitVariables
{
        // Add a constructor:
        public TransitVariables(string stopLocation, string name)
        {
            this.StopLocation = stopLocation;
            this.Name = name;
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stopLocation))
            {
                 var items = stopLocation.Split(',');
                 this.Lon = double.Parse(items[0]);
                 this.Lat = double.Parse(items[1]);
                 this.Alt = double.Parse(items[2]);
            }
        }

        public string StopLocation { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Lat { get; set; }
        public double Lon { get; set; }
        public double Alt { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Reed, The problem is there are multiple StopLocations and I need to convert all of them to be bound to Bing Pushpin Location

Comment: @Rhys: The above code should work - just make a method that does this conversion, and call it in your query to set the values...

Comment: Im not really sure how I would implement that into my code. Any chance you could edit my code and show me? Sorry to be a pain, I have just been trying to get this for weeks and am limited by my lack of C# knowledge.